# enable user input in the activity behind the popup (custom dialog)

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog

I created a custom search dialog above my activity and I update the result based on entered text, but then the activity doesn't respond to user touch as search dialog is still present on the screen.

I think due to dialog, activity is not able to get user touch event.. so is there a way to enable user touch for the same?

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dialog is implemented as a transparent activity with Dialog theme ,so dont try to get handlers of back screen . instead replace dialog by a view and shitch visibilities of Views VISIBLE/INVISIBLE/GONE

Comment: Actually, I tried to call backActivity.dispatchTouchEvent() from dispatchTouch of my class which extends dialog and touches it worked just fine.

Comment: @sandrstar: Can you please explain it a little more?

Comment: @BugsHappen It means, create custom dialog class, override dispatchTouch() in dialog and inside it, just call activities  backActivity.dispatchTouchEvent(). This way touches from dialog will be transferred to the activity.

Answer (score 0):

There are some useful `Window` flags for this

`WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE` and/or `FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE` for rare cases like mine - no touches in the popup

`WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL` to allow touch behind and also in the dialog

You would set these using `dialog.window.addFlags(..)` or, if you know what you're doing, `dialog.window.setFlags(..)`. (THis is Kotlin syntax)